# Posting object as xml to Solr

Tags: c#, solr

I am working with solr for the first time, and I am having some troubles making a post web request to put products into my solr library.

This is my code:

```
private static void PostProductToSolr(Product p)
{
    string solrFieldsXML =
            "<add>" + "\n" +
                "<doc>" + "\n" +
                    "<field name=\"id\">" + p.ID + "</field>" + "\n" +
                    "<field name=\"name_s\">" + p.Name + "</field>" + "\n" +
                    "<field name=\"title_s\">" + p.Title + "</field>" + "\n" +
                    "<field name=\"ShortDescription_txt\">" + p.ShortDescription + "</field>" + "\n" +
                    "<field name=\"LongDescription_txt\">" + p.LongDescription + "</field>" + "\n" +
                    "<field name=\"ShortSummaryDescription_txt\">" + p.ShortSummary + "</field>" + "\n" +
                    "<field name=\"LongSummaryDescription_txt\">" + p.LongSummary + "</field>" + "\n" +
                    "<field name=\"price_d\">" + p.Price + "</field>" + "\n" +
                    "<field name=\"category_s\">" + p.FkCategoryId + "</field>" + "\n" +
                "</doc>" + "\n" +
            "</add>";
    Post(solrFieldsXML);
    //File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\ssb\Documents\ProductXml\product_" + p.ID + ".xml", solrFieldsXML);
}

private static void Post(string body)
{
    string url = @"http://localhost:8983/solr/LenovoProducts/update";

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(responseString);

}
```

And when I run it i get 400 bad request.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHTgb.png)

EDIT: It manages to post the first product but still throws an error on the response as seen on the image, which stops the program from posting the next product.

This is my solr log:
[Solr Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXfEH.png)

Comment: Please check solr logs, they might have more logs describing the error.

Comment: I added a picture of the log thanks

Comment: Seems there is an issue with XML being sent to Solr. Check the validity of XML format. Is this happening for all products?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using [SolrNet](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet)? It'll do this automagically for you. The error you're seeing is probably because you're not escaping the content of the XML values properly and there's a `<b>` tag in there somewhere. Use a library and you won't have to concern yourself with getting all these details right.

Comment: Im a first time user of Solr, trying to figure out how it works .. I didn't know SolrNet and I wouldn't know how to properly use it.